# Documentation for Data Processing Scripts

Tags: r, python-3.x

I was wondering if anyone can share best practices to work on **documentation** for data processing scripts. I have written R scripts for my Proof of Concept Project and looking to write a summarized document for other departments.

Comment: This question might be off topic but I think people can give some really interesting answers.
I would look at documenting R packages in general, particularly for CRAN, [r-pkgs](https://r-pkgs.org/man.html), [R package primer](https://kbroman.org/pkg_primer/pages/cran.html), and [rOpenSci](https://kbroman.org/pkg_primer/pages/cran.html).